# how to find common keys from two dict with difference in values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get the keys whose values differ in both dictionaries
e.g:

```
items1=['a','b','c']
price1=[1,2,3]
dictA= dict(zip(items1, price1))

items2=['a','b']
price2=[1,3]
dictB=dict(zip(items2,price2))
```

so the difference will be ['b'] as this key is the only difference

i tried using `set(dictA.items()).symmetric_difference(dictB.items())`, but this is also returning the key:value {'c':3}

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the common keys, and drop keys having matching values in `dictA` and `dictB`:

```
In [3]: {key for key in dictA.keys() & dictB if dictA[key] != dictB[key]}
Out[3]: {'b'}
```

Comment: won me for 10 secs, great answer

Comment: Note: this does not worth for Py2: `{key for key in dictA.keys() & dictB if dictA[key] != dictB[key]}` -> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'dict'`

Comment: @TemporalWolf yes, I see no need to support Python 2 in my answers

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over the intersection.

```
delta = [k for k in (set(dictA) & set(dictB)) if (dictB[k] - dictA[k])]
```

Comment: What if dictionary values aren't numeric?

Comment: True.  These things are a race, you know.  =c)

Comment: Use `dictB[k] != dictA[k]` instead. Handles everything and it's good for all